# How to return arraylist using restful webservices in java?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I want to return values in the json format. I am using (`MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`) for to return the values. How to return the `ArrayList` using this? 
Example:

```
[
  {
    "node_title": "Ambivalence About Government Will Be Topic at next Lecture ",
    "nid": "Topic - Get the Government Off of Our Backs – There Ought to Be a Law: Reconciling Our National Ambivalence About Government."
  },
  {
    "node_title": "Recycling initiative gains steam under new director",
    "nid": "University administrators listened and hired a sustainability coordinator whose main focus has been to heighten recycling efforts and awareness."
  },
  {
    "node_title": "Special Week to Combat Hate and Discrimination",
    "nid": "For the seventh year, University students will observe “Why Do You Hate Me?” Week, which will run from March 28th through April 2nd."
  },
  {
    "node_title": "AUSP joins Nursing School on mission trip to Caribbean",
    "nid": "The School of Audiology and Speech-Language Pathology during spring break went to Dominican Republic to provide much-needed assistance to a school for deaf and impoverished children."
  }
]
```

Please guide me.

Comment: Is this JSON something you're getting from somewhere (like a web service) and you want to parse into an arraylist?

Comment: Look at http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to parse this into java code, you can do something like this:
First, get [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), a google library to work with JSON.

Next, define a class like:

```
class Node {
    String node_title;
    String nid;
}
```

Then you can do

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<Node>>(){}.getType();
List<Node> details = gson.fromJson(myJsonString, collectionType);
```